# Do you have any suggestion for a website regarding time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, references

I'm new to time series analysis and I would like to know if any of you has any suggestion on website to check out about this topic.

Comment: Check Rob Hyndman's [ebook](https://otexts.com/fpp3/).

Comment: Time series are a huge topic, it would be helpful if you could narrow your interest down a little. If your interest is specifically about forecasting, [here is our canonical thread about forecasting resources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/559908/1352).

Comment: This very site has a lot on time series, I would definitely recommend browsing [tag:time-series]