Forecasting RNN and LSTM without X_test
Dear StackExchange Community,
My data is composed of only 1 time series variable (Stock prices of an asset)
I have splitted it to train and test subsets.
I have tarined an RNN and LSTM models with X_train and Y_train.
The resources that I have used (Books, Courses and blogs) suggesting to use X_test for the prediction. The prediction RMSE is too good to be true. I am supposing it's because I am using for prediction the same dataset (X_test) as Y_test.
What book, course, blog would you suggest me to use in order to forecast the future value without using X_test.(I think multi-step-ahead?)
Best Regards

If you used the same data for X_train and Y_train, then you modeled Y_train on itself. In forecasting Y_test, you would need to know Y_test to feed it into X_test. This is circular. If you have only the stock price data, then leave X_train blank. (Or use lagged values of the time series, with lags determined by your forecast horizon.)

Hi @StephanKolassa. Thank you for your comment. I have tried to use 0 for all values of X_test and gor significantly higher RMSE value. Then I have used the last 1770 values of the Y_train for X_test and the result became a bit better. Could you please indicate a paper or source where I can validate this approach?

Is your RMSE in-sample or for a holdout sample? In-sample RMSE is useless. You may want to take a look at the resources for forecasting we collected here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/559908/1352

@StephanKolassa my RMSE is out-of-sample, it is the data that my model hasn't seen before.

If you’re testing out-of-sample, what’s the problem?

Problem is I don't have X_test values. However, as @StephanKolassa suggested I am going to use shift of -len(y_test) of x_train for x_test. (Better saying last values of X_train I am going to reserve for the prediction

What is your X_train? It sounds like you just have one time series and want to use a model (LSTM in this case) to use values of the time series to predict future values of the time series.

I don't quite understand how you have out-of-sample RMSE values without having X_test data. Do you mean that you get those values by feeding in the actuals of the series? That would just explain the series by itself, so of course it is not useful for actual forecasting (and I would be hesitant to call this setup a "holdout test").
